# how to roll back a sequence in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have declared this sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[Monitor_Seq] 
 AS [int]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 2147483647
 CACHE 
GO
```

and I use it like this:

```
declare @y int
declare @i int
select @y = 1

while @y < 100 begin

    SELECT @i = NEXT VALUE FOR Monitor_Seq;
    PRINT CAST ( @I AS VARCHAR)


    -- use @i here


    select @y = @y + 1

end /*while*/
```

the question is:

where it says in the code:

-- use @i here

suppose I decide not to carry on with a particular number, how can I revert it back my sequence?
Let's say when I get the NEXT VALUE = 10
situation made me NOT to carry on with the number 10.

I want that on the next time I get the

```
 SELECT @i = NEXT VALUE FOR Monitor_Seq;
```

I want to get @i = 10 again.
is this possible?

Comment: I can't answer your question because we don't use sequences, but I invite you to realize that if this proc may be run simulatnaeously for mulitple users, rolling back a sequence could be a very bad idea. If you generate a number of 100 and someone simultaneously running with you gets 101 and another gets 102 and you return to reuse 100, you had better test to see the effect on 101 and 102. Could they get assigned twice?

Comment: Why do you need a contiguous numbering system saved on the row? Would a windowing function at query time be able to produce the same result?

Comment: If you are using number generation techniques like identity and sequence, you need to accept that gaps are just a fact of life. Stop caring about gaps. If gaps are catastrophic for some reason, either fix **that**, or roll your own serializable number generator. Just realize that (a) preventing gaps is expensive and (b) you still can't prevent *deletes* that cause gaps.

Comment: Now thinking about it, I actually do not need a continuous numbering system, on this situation.

Comment: The bigger question is why in the world do you use a sequence in a loop? I am guessing that is for inserts, that should be done in a set based approach instead of looping.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree with you :) that was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restart a sequence:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE Monitor_Seq RESTART WITH 10;
```